# Send invitation to any user of google chats (is it possible?)

Tags: perl, gmail, xmpp, google-talk, invitation

I try to realize simple code on perl which should just get/send messages from/to gtalk accounts. I use Net::XMPP::*

modules. All works just fine for users, who are my friends (in my "buddy" list). 
But i can't send message to unknown user. I know, that for this case i must send an invitation first, but

Net::XMPP::* don't provide this possibility. There is only one way to invite person - construct my own xml according

to "XEP-0155 Stanza Session Negotiation" protocol. But this doesn't work correct. When i send xml to server, it

returns error "service-unavailable".

I send:

```
<message to='TEST@gmail.com'>
 <sxde xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/sxde'
   xmlns:sxde='http://jabber.org/protocol/sxde#metadata'
   session='0AEF4278DC4B6577'
   id='b'>
  <negotiation>
    <invitation>
      <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/whiteboard' />
    </invitation>
  </negotiation>
 </sxde>
</message>
```

before my message.

ANSWER:

```
<message from='' to='ME@gmail.com/TALKCDDCCE63' type='error'>
  <sxde id='b' session='0AEF4278DC4B6577' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/sxde' xmlns:sxde='http://jabber.org/protocol/sxde#metadata'>
    <negotiation>
      <invitation>
        <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/whiteboard'/>
      </invitation>
    </negotiation>
  </sxde>
<nos:x value='disabled' xmlns:nos='google:nosave'/>
<arc:record otr='false' xmlns:arc='http://jabber.org/protocol/archive'/>
<error code='503' type='cancel'>
    <service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
</error>
</message>
```

Maybe i lost smth or should send another info before (or after..) ?

Or maybe there are another way to send message without any invitation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You need to authenticate your jid, then you could send message stanza to xmpp server. Subscription required only for presence notifications.

```
<message to='ME@gmail.com/TALKCDDCCE63' type='chat' xmlns='jabber:client'>
<body>TEST MESSAGE</body>
</message>
```

Comment: As i understand, my auth process run correct, please, take a look at my code and said if there is smth wrong: 
<pre>
 <code>
    $xmpp = new Net::XMPP::Client->new(debuglevel=>2,debugfile=>'SOME_FILE'); my $xmppsid = $xmpp->{SESSION}->{id}; $xmpp->{STREAM}->{SIDS}->{$xmppsid}->{hostname} = 'gmail.com'; my @connect_status = $xmpp->AuthSend( username=>$login password=>$password, resource=>'TALK', hostname=>'gmail.com' ); exit if $connect_status[0] ne 'ok' ; $xmpp->Process(); 
    </code>
    </pre>I should send to server smth else?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
I just need to send

```
$xmpp->Send("<presence to='$address' type='subscribe' /></presence>")
```

That's all